# Mapping a ForeignKey with another class

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my Django Models.py

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True, null=True)  

class Test2(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True) 
    sequence = models.IntegerField(db_column='Sequence') 
    test1id = models.ForeignKey('Test1', models.DO_NOTHING,null=False, db_column='Test1Id')
```

what i am trying to do is to ensure when the Test1 id is saved, it automatically fills in the test1id.

Comment: you want auto create the `Test2` or be ensure that Test2.test1id.name will be new?

Comment: You can have many Test1 in your table, how do you want Test2 be filled with Test1... which registry from Test2 will be filled by which registry from Test1?

Comment: @BearBrown i want to ensure that when my Test1 is saved, its primary key is saved at test1id.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do here, but if you want to implement any post save actions for model look at [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/). Particularly at [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal.

Here is example usage of `post_save` signal, for model `Test1`(suppose you want to create new `Test2` object):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Test1)
def create_test2(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Test2.objects.create(test1id=instance)
```

Comment: i have a function in views.py that saves the name from the Test1 name and Test2 sequence from post method. and i want to save the created id in test1 to be saved in test2.test1id

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the save method:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        super(Test1, self).save()
        Test2.objects.create(test1id=self)
    else:
        super(Test1, self).save()
```

So when you save Test1, a Test2 entry is created

Comment: is this in views.py or in models.py?

Comment: in the model :)